# How to prove one hash function can produce a length-fixed output? Is it related to modulus(n)?

Tags: encryption

Consider the following hash function based on RSA. The key < n, e > is known to the public. A message M is represented by blocks of predefined fixed size $M_1, M_2, M_3, ..., M_m$ such that $M_i < n$. The hash is constructed as: encrypt the first block, XOR the result with the second block and encrypt again, etc. For example, the hash value of a message consisting of two blocks is calculated by

$()=(_1,_2)=(({_1}^e \bmod n) \oplus _2)^ \bmod n$

Does this hash function satisfy each of the following requirements?

Q1. Fixed output size?

My answer: Because any output is limited to the modulus(n), the hash function can produce fixed output size?(I think of it for a long time, but I still wonder about it)

Q2. Easy to calculate?

My answer: Because the hash function just contain encryption and XOR operations, it is easy to calculate.(Is it right or completed?)

Comment: Is $0$ a valid plaintext block? If that is the case, If the number $0$ is always encoded to the bitstring $00\ldots 0$ then wouldn't a plaintext $M$ and $M' = O|M$ always collide under the hash function?

Comment: @MarcIlunga: actually, it's broken worse than that - the second preimage problem is easy.  However, he didn't ask about the security of the hash function...

Answer (score 1):

> My answer: Because any output is limited to the modulus(n), the hash function can produce fixed output size?(I think of it for a long time, but I still wonder about it)

That's correct as long as you expect statically sized output from the modular exponentiation. RSA actually uses a function called I2OSP which converts an integer to an octet string for this. Obviously, otherwise the answer is no, because the number returned from the modular exponentiation is just required to be smaller than the modulus $n$.

Note that XOR is a binary operation while modular exponentiation acts on numbers. So there is some conversion function required before the XOR as well.

> My answer: Because the hash function just contain encryption and XOR operations, it is easy to calculate.(Is it right or completed?)

Define "easy". It is a simple function, but it requires messages that are between 0 and N (exclusive). Furthermore, compared to actual cryptographic hash functions, it is very inefficient as modular exponentiation - even with a small exponent for the public key - is quite slow. Finally, the input size is limited as well, while generic hash functions commonly can have very large messages (virtually unbounded input).

Comment: Thanks! However, I still wonder. The reason why the hash function can produce fixed output size is because of I2OSP? And the function is not easy to calculate because of exponentiation operation?

Comment: The problem with RSA is that the number size is bounded by the modulus size. However, that's the *maximum* size; the result may be (significantly) smaller than the modulus. So you need some function to create a statically sized encoding of the number, regardless of the value it has, and that's I2OSP. As for "easy"; it depends on your definition of "easy". The calculation isn't that complex and usually present in any big integer library, but it is not efficient.

Answer (score 1):

> Q1. Fixed output size?

The output size is limited to $\lceil\log_2 n\rceil$-bit strings, although it does not give a uniform distribution on $\lceil\log_2 n\rceil$-bit strings: all of the outputs are necessarily below $n$ when interpreted as integers.  This means outputs can be easily distinguished from uniform random bit strings—a little under half of the $\lceil\log_2 n\rceil$-bit strings will never appear as output.

> Q2. Easy to calculate?

It depends on your metric for easy—it won't beat any speed records over typical collision-resistant hash functions like SHA-256—but it is certainly feasible.

---

What properties does it have as a ‘hash’?  One way to look at it is an iteration of $$h_0 = 0, \qquad h_i = f(h_{i-1}, m_i) = \pi(h_{i-1} \oplus m_i),$$ where $\pi$ is the RSA trapdoor permutation $\pi(m) = m^e \bmod n$.

- **Preimage resistance.**  Obviously, there's a back door because this is a public-key cryptosystem: anyone who knows the secret factors $p$ and $q$ of $n$ can compute a preimage for any hash $h$ by computing $h^d \bmod n$ where $d$ solves $e d \equiv 1 \pmod{\operatorname{lcm}(p - 1, q - 1)}$.  But otherwise, finding a preimage means computing $e^{\mathit{th}}$ roots modulo $n$, so this is clearly preimage-resistant but with a back door.
- **Uniformity.**  As noted above, the output is easily distinguished from uniform random *bit strings*.  So this is not a good substitute for, *e.g.*, SHA-256, which is used in random oracle applications where the bit strings are expected to resemble independent uniform random bit strings.
- **Length extension.**  If $H(m_1) = h$, then $H(m_1 \mathbin\| m_2) = (h \oplus m_2)^e \bmod n$, which can be computed without knowledge of $m_1$.  SHA-256 has the same bug; newer designs like SHA-3 and BLAKE2 avoid this mistake.
- **Collision resistance.**  $H(H(m_1) \oplus m_2) = ({m_1}^e \oplus m_2)^e = H(m_1 \mathbin\| m_2)$, so the messages $H(m_1) \oplus m_2$ and $m_1 \mathbin\| m_2$ collide under $H$.  Oops.

On the other hand, the reason the collision attack and the length extension attack work is that one message ($m_1$) is a prefix of another message ($m_1 \mathbin\| m_2$), which brings the same type of problem that naive CBC-MAC exhibits—essentially, this is like CBC-MAC with an encryption oracle but no decryption oracle.  I leave it as an exercise for the reader to ascertain whether a prefix-free encoding of messages in this scheme yields collision resistance.